# after i login as another user, how can i return back to my account without loging out and re-login in laravel 7

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-7

I used this to allow a user to login as another user.

`Auth::loginUsingId($userId, true);`

now I want to create a button that will route the user back to his own account when clicked in laravel-7.

Comment: is there any parent child  relation where you should defined that

Comment: No. its just an admin logging in to a user account and he wants to go back to his own account without logging out

Comment: you can try storing the previous userID in a session. then retrieve it when you "go back" to your admin account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[use laravel impersonate](https://github.com/404labfr/laravel-impersonate)

by using this you will be able to login into other user account without logout from your account

Comment: yes it will work when you send the id of user which you impersonate through api